# Using vue-devtools with composition-api when returning a render function (e.g. JSX)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jsx, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Since switching to the [composition-api](https://composition-api.vuejs.org) and returning a [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) (in my case constructed using [JSX with TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) to allow typing support in the template), I've lost the ability for [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to inspect [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). This is because they are no longer directly exposed by the component (props are still available).

How can I get good TypeScript support in my templates, while retaining the ability for vue-devtools to inspect the computed properties?

Here is an example of using `.vue` files with the composition-api that was friendly towards vue-devtools, but had no TypeScript support in the template:

`SomeComponent.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>{{ computedProperty }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  export default defineComponent({
    name: "SomeComponent",
    props: { 
      // ...
    },
    setup(props, ctx) {
      const computedProperty = computed(() => {
        // return ...some calc
      })
  
      return {
        computedProperty
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Here's an example using `.tsx` files that has proper TypeScript support in the template, but vue-devtools can no longer inspect the `computedProperty` directly:

`SomeComponent.tsx`

```
export default defineComponent({
    name: "SomeComponent",
    props: { 
      // ...
    },
    setup(props, ctx) {
      const computedProperty = computed(() => {
        // return ...some calc
      })
  
      return () => (
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>{ computedProperty.value }</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

How can I get the best of both worlds?

Comment: Here's a relevant GitHub issue to watch: [`vuejs/vue-devtools`#1199](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/1199)

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default defineComponent({
    name: "SomeComponent",
    props: { 
      // ...
    },
    setup(props, ctx) {
      const computedProperty = computed(() => {
        // return ...some calc
      })

      return { computedProperty }
    },
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>{ this.computedProperty.value }</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

Comment: I can take a guess, having the setup and render separately allows vue-devtools to track the properties, but when I previously tried this the templates did not have type support.